# Business Dynamics 365 API - Not able to get Web/ecommerce enabled items only

Tags: dynamics-365-sales

Using Dynamics 365 APIs, able to get all the items created on Microsoft - Business Control. But there is an option to make the item visible on the Web/commerce. Through API not able to get a parameter that specifies whether the web is on the Web or not. As a result, returning all the items created but the Client requirement is to display the items that are web/commerce-enabled.

https://ansit-tarannum.tinytake.com/msc/NzU4NjA2MF8yMDU0OTM1OA
It will be highly helpful if anyone can help with this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/api-reference/v2.0/api/dynamics_item_get

I went through all the APIs but didn't find any parameter that indicates the Web-published items.

I am expecting to get that specific parameter that distinguish between published and not published items on Web/commerce.

Or any API that has this data along with mapping with item id.

Thanks
Tarannum